# e HVL (IEEE 1647): How to set 'X' value?

Tags: specman, e

I would like to initialize some variables in my verification environment to 'X' value. How can I set 'X' value in e?

Thank you for your help

Comment: The proper spelling for the hardware verification language is lower case `e`. Upper case `E` refers to a programming language for secure distributed computing: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(programming_language)

Comment: I usually also add `e (IEEE 1647)` to make sure that people understand I mean the HVL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set values other than `0` and `1` using the MVL (multi-valued logic) functions. For a one-bit wide signal this would be:

```
sig.put_mvl(MVL_X);
```

It's also possible to assign multi-bit signals by writing:

```
wide_sig.put_mvl_list({ MVL_X, MVL_X, ... });
```

These methods only apply to ports. If you want to assign variables to `X` you need to declare them as being of type `mvl` or `list of mvl`.